# Access Query If/or condition

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to write an OR statement in the query design in Access and its not working!
The statementis below:

`Duration:If([Status2]="Q","2.5 Hours",IIf([Status2]=WS,"4 Hours", IIf([Status2]=MG,"3 Hours 15 Mins",IIf([Status2]=ID,"3.5 Hours"))))`

Comment: What do you mean that it's not working?  Do you mean you are prevented from writing the OR expression or that you can write the expression but it doesn't give you the correct results?

Answer (score 1):

As Zaider89 pointed out, you left off an `I` from the first `IIf()`.

Also you're comparing `[Status2]` to 4 different values: Q; WS; MG; ID.  You enclosed the first of those values with quotation marks, but not the others.  That makes me suspect the db engine would treat the unquoted values as parameters and ask you to supply values for WS, MG, and ID.

The last of your `IIf()` expressions includes a "true part" but no "false part":

```
IIf([Status2]=ID,"3.5 Hours")
```

You could fix those problems, but I suggest you consider using the [Switch Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/switch-function-HA001228918.aspx) instead.  Try the following on a single line in the query design grid in a column next to your `IIf()` attempt.

```
Duration:Switch([Status2]="Q","2.5 Hours",
[Status2]="WS","4 Hours",
[Status2]="MG","3 Hours 15 Mins",
[Status2]="ID","3.5 Hours")
```

That `Switch()` approach looks better to me.  However I think it would be better still to create a separate look-up table with one column for `[Status2]` and another for the mapped value.  Then join that table into your query.  After you create the table, it's easy to use it in your queries and I think it's easier to understand than approaches using `Switch()` or nested `IIf()` expressions.  It would also be easier to extend when you need to add new conditions --- just add them as rows in the look-up table.

Answer (score 0):

If that is a direct copy from your access database you are missing an I on the If at the beginning. it should be IIF not IF.